# Linq get the value from the var returned

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have the below code I am getting a distinct value from the datatables and then using the value to select on that datatable.

```
string ccId = d.ToString();
```

is being returned as "{ id = B08 }" -- I just need B08 how can I get that value?

```
var distinctIds = dt.AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(s => new { id = s.Field<string>("CCId"),})
                  .Distinct().ToList();



foreach (var d in distinctIds)
{
     string ccId = d.ToString();
     DataTable selectedTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(r => r.Field<string>("CCId") == ccId).CopyToDataTable();
     CreateFile(selectedTable);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `d.ToString()` just call `d.id`

Comment: Also consider not creating an anonymous class in your query `Select(s => s.Field<string>("CCId"))`

Answer (score 3):

You are forcing this structure when populating `distinctIds`. By removing the anonymous (new) call in your select you will have a list of the values only.

```
var distinctIds = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(s => s.Field<string>("CCId"))
                    .Distinct().ToList();
```